# Will rewriting the Joomla system files, remove my articles and data?

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5

As I cannot access to my admin area, I was told that Joomla system files might have problems and the best is to download the latest version and rewrite it on my host.  My website is running and up. So if I replace the Joomla package on my host, will it remove or change anything on my website? anything that I have on the website, such as plugins, template, articles, music, mySQL, and so on. Will they change?
It is based on Joomla 1.5.

If yes, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to do it on your live server because you may broke your site. Instead of this prepare a local server and download your site to it. Then download a dump of your server database and restore it locally.

On your local copy you only need to change the configuration.php file with your local database settings (username, password and database) and paths to tmp and cache directories.

When the local site is up and running you can try to replace old files with the new ones, but don't overwrite the configuration.php file. Before replacing files is not a bad idea to keep a copy of your site files. By the way, don't try to overwrite with files from higher versions than 1.5 : it simply won't work. The last stable package for the (discontinued) 1.5 is 1.5.26, available through JoomlaCode : http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/

If this solves your issue then you can upload the files downloaded from Joomla to your server  (except the configuration.php) .

Regards!

Edit: as you can see, your articles will not be removed, as they are stored on the database.